# ANR Input dispatching timed out when get location & address (GPS)

Tags: android, android-gps, google-location-services

I am trying to get last location and convert it to address using `JobIntentService` then send the result to UI using `ResultReceiver`. All working normally except for some specific devices which resulted in ANR.

Here is the log from Android Vitals:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x74d8de18 self=0x7316614c00
| sysTid=17084 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x739dd2f548
| state=S schedstat=( 613944004 54839462 530 ) utm=50 stm=10 core=0 HZ=100
| stack=0x7ff0b1f000-0x7ff0b21000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes=
#00  pc 000000000006fdcc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
#01  pc 00000000000291b8  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
#02  pc 000000000005ac14  /system/lib64/libbinder.so 
(android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+260)
#03  pc 000000000005b9bc  /system/lib64/libbinder.so 
(android::IPCThreadState::waitForResponse(android::Parcel*, int*)+60)
#04  pc 000000000005b808  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::transact(int, 
unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+176)
#05  pc 00000000000516f8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::BpBinder::transact(unsigned int, 
android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+72)
#06  pc 00000000001336f0  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so 
(android_os_BinderProxy_transact(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+152)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:1161)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getFromLocation (ILocationManager.java:958)
at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation (Geocoder.java:133)
at com.xxx.app.service.GetLocationService.lambda$getLocation$0$GetLocationService 
(GetLocationService.java:75) //This is the problem
at com.xxx.app.service.-$$Lambda$GetLocationService$Hk1ggmi6vOd6RCH3cvtOt4N8-Hc.onSuccess (lambda)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run (unavailable:4)
- locked <0x0c213f10> (a java.lang.Object)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7070)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

As you can see, the problem reside within my service. Here is my service class:

```
public class GetLocationService extends JobIntentService {
private final static String TAG = GetLocationService.class.getSimpleName();
protected ResultReceiver receiver;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private Geocoder geocoder;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
private LocationModel model;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_RECEIVER);
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    getLocation();
}

// Static method to enqueue work
public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
    enqueueWork(context, GetLocationService.class, GET_LOCATION, intent);
}

// Get current location of user and send it back to UI through interface
public void getLocation() {
    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                if (location != null) {
                    model = new LocationModel();

                    String latitude = null;
                    String longitude = null;
                    List<Address> addressList = null;

                    try {
                        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1); // This is the problem
                    } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (latitude != null && longitude != null && addressList != null) {
                        model.setLatitude(latitude);
                        model.setLongitude(longitude);
                        model.setAddressList(addressList);

                        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT, model);
                    } else {
                        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILED_RESULT, null);
                    }
                }
            });
}

// Send the result to receiver
private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, LocationModel model) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(Constants.LOCATION_RECEIVER_RESULT_DATA_KEY, model);
    receiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
}
```

Anyone got a clue? Thank you.

Comment: in which Android version it is crashing? Because its look  like you are using Java 8 Lambda function in your code and it is not supporting to the older device.

Comment: This problem only happened in vivo devices (Android 9).

Comment: I think the problem might lie with the Geocoder, actually - the documentation for getFromLocation says "It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread." The handleWork method is called on a background thread, so perhaps try switching from adding listeners to the task returned from getLastLocation to blocking on it (using Tasks.await) to get the result, and if it's successful and a location exists then go on to do the call to Geocoder directly before returning the results via the result receiver?